# Upload video remotly to youtube via API

Tags: php, youtube-api, remote-server

**Task:**

User "uploads" video on my website (html form, php) directly to youtube via API on my chanel (without the file being upload to my server first).

**Question:**

Is this possible or do i have to temporarily save the video to my server?

*at the google resources [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads) there is no hint how to do that.*

*There [IS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget#Requirements) a upload widget to embed (iframe) in your website BUT it requires the user to login into their own chanel which is not wanted? when this widget could be routed to our youtube chanel it would be THE solution.*

*A project, [youtube direct lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/), doesn't work anymore without users loging-in to their account.*

Maybe, alternatively, you know another service provider than youtube that allows you to embed an upload widget with event callbacks such as ID and videoUrl to use...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There IS a possibility see [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/useyourdrive-google-drive-plugin-for-wordpress/6219776)

i purchased it but don't have the time to investigate code for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not suggest letting users upload any video to your own account. Therefore all OAuth mechanisms let user upload it to his/her own account. Only then via YouTube Direct Lite you can moderate (simply select videos to be added on your playlist).